# Simulink model error

Tags: matlab, simulink

I've had to create the Simulink Diagram after this picture:

[image: Diagram]

My answer is this one:

[image: Simulink image]

I've gave some values to `a`, `b` and `c` (like 3, 4 and 5), but when I try to run it, it gives me the following warning:

> Warning: The model 'ex2_2' does not have continuous states, hence Simulink is using the
>   solver 'VariableStepDiscrete' instead of solver 'ode45'. You can disable this diagnostic by
>   explicitly specifying a discrete solver in the solver tab of the Configuration Parameters
>   dialog, or by setting the 'Automatic solver parameter selection' diagnostic to 'none' in the
>   Diagnostics tab of the Configuration Parameters dialog
>
> Warning: 'ex2_2/Unit Delay' is discrete, yet is inheriting a continuous sample time; consider
>   replacing unit delay with a memory block. When a unit delay block inherits continuous sample
>   time, its behavior is the same as the memory block. Unit delay block's time delay will not be
>   fixed and could change with each time step. This might be unexpected behavior. Normally, a
>   unit delay block uses discrete sample time. You can disable this diagnostic by setting the
>   'Discrete used as continuous' diagnostic to 'none' in the Sample Time group on the
>   Diagnostics pane of the Configuration Parameters dialog box. "

and the output (<kbd>scope</kbd>) it's just a step signal...

I don't know where I'm wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

You've built the model correctly, but did not configure it correctly.

When running the model as-is, what will happen is the following:

1. The <kbd>Step</kbd> block is a continuous-time source by default (it's `Sample Time` setting is `0`).
2. Simulink sees that the <kbd>Step</kbd> is connected to the <kbd>Unit delay</kbd> block, which is guaranteed to have constant output during minor steps (unlike <kbd>Memory</kbd> blocks)
3. According to the [documentation on sample times](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/types-of-sample-time.html):

   > [...] Simulink sets [Fixed-in-Minor step] as either an inherited sample time or as an alteration to a user specification of 0 (continuous). This setting is equivalent to, and therefore converted to, the fastest discrete rate when you use a fixed-step solver.

   Continuous sample time degrades to Fixed-in-Minor-Step rather than Discrete-time in the context of Variable-step solvers. Variable step size is used to speed up simulations (larger steps are taken when accuracy allows it), but requires trickery to compute, for example, the exact time at which the step triggers (the "`Enable zero-crossing detection`" tick box in the <kbd>Step</kbd> block's options). So, Simulink's best way forward in this particular situation is to convert the sample time of the <kbd>Step</kbd> block into Fixed-in-Minor-Step, which is propagated forward and inherited by all other blocks in the model.
4. This is usually an awkward type of sample time, which is effectively not continuous-time, but still seen by all blocks as such. Therefore, the inherently discrete-time <kbd>Unit delay</kbd> will complain about being driven by a continuous-time signal (your 2<sup>nd</sup> warning), and Simulink itself will complain about the complete lack of "real" continuous-time blocks anywhere, while being instructed to use a continuous-time solver, `ode45` (your 1<sup>st</sup> warning).

As usual in software development: it's ***always*** best to be explicit, about ***everything***. In this case, the simplest way out of this is to explicitly specify a discrete-time, fixed-step solver in the model configuration dialog. That way, the continuous-time from the step will be automatically converted into discrete-time for the <kbd>Unit delay</kbd>.

Comment: How can I specify a discrete-time, fixed-step solver in the model configuration dialog? Sorry, I'm kinda new to simulink...

Comment: @LaurentiuAdrianParaschiv Unless it's changed drastically (I'm on R2010a), open the model config dialog (Ctrl+E). On the left you can select a configuration category. Select `Solver`. Then, on the right, under `Solver Options`, select `Fixed Step` **type**, and `discrete-time` **solver**. Additionally, you may specify the sample time explicitly. With a setting of `auto`, Simulink will select a sample time such that 50 steps will be taken in total. You might want some more for better-looking scope outputs.

Comment: now it gives me the following error: Unable to determine a fixed step size based on the sample times in the model
'ex2_2', because the model does not have any discrete sample times.  Picking a fixed step
size of (0.2) based on simulation start and stop times.  You can disable this diagnostic by
explicitly specifying a fixed step size in the Solver pane of the Configuration Parameters
dialog box, or setting the 'Automatic solver parameter selection' diagnostic to 'none' in the
Solver group on the Diagnostics pane of the Configuration Parameters dialog box.

Comment: @LaurentiuAdrianParaschiv and if you specify a sample time of 0.2 *explicitly*?

Answer (score 0):

The block diagram you want to implement is a discrete-time system. Since there are no Ordinary Differential Equations (ODE) but only their discrete counterpart (Finite-differences equations), you do not need an ODE solver as the warning 1 points out.

In discrete-time systems you have to specify your sample time in order *to approach* to a continuous-time representation where every single instant `t` is built up by the discrete integer `n` and its progressions (`n+1`, `n+2`, and so on) as `t = nT` where T is your sample time; Simulink basically expects that you respect this kind of logic, then asks for a sample time. By default Simulink sets it variable which may lead the result "out of track". This is what the warning 2 points out.

Solution: In the 'Model Configuration Parameters' menu, at the Solver tab, set 'Fixed-Step' as Type. The pane will change with a field related to the sample-time (Fixed-step size); set then a Sample time in seconds different than "auto" (e.g. 0.01). This will solve the warning 2. Still in the Solver menu, set also 'Discrete (no continuous states)' instead of any other useless solver. This will solve the warning 1.